# Logging to console with Pyramid pshell

Tags: python-3.x, pyramid

In the process of developing a Pyramid web application, I've found it very useful to use the command-line `pshell` to load the application and interact with various code. However, log statements are not echoed on the console, and I'm not sure why.

For instance, lets say in `common.utilities.general` I have a function:

```
import logging

log = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def my_util():
    log.debug("Executing utility.")
    return "Utility was executed."
```

Then in my command line:

```
(pyenv)rook:swap nateford$ pshell src/local.ini 
2015-10-08 14:44:01,081 INFO  [common.orm.pymongo_core][MainThread] PyMongo Connection to replica set successful: localhost:27017
2015-10-08 14:44:01,082 INFO  [common.orm.pymongo_core][MainThread] Connected to Mongo Database = turnhere
Python 3.4.3 (default, Mar 10 2015, 14:53:35) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.56)] on darwin
Type "help" for more information.

Environment:
  app          The WSGI application.
  registry     Active Pyramid registry.
  request      Active request object.
  root         Root of the default resource tree.
  root_factory Default root factory used to create `root`.

>>> from common.utilities.general import my_util
>>> my_util()
'Utility was executed.'
>>>
```

As you can see, there is no log to the console. I would expect:

```
>>> from common.utilities.general import my_util
>>> my_util()
[some date/server info][DEBUG]: Executing utility.
'Utility was executed.'
>>>
```

Here is the (relevant) contents of my `local.ini` file:

```
<Various elided application settings>
###
# logging configuration
# http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.5-branch/narr/logging.html
###

[loggers]
keys = root, common, webapp, services, sqlalchemy

[handlers]
keys = console, applog

[formatters]
keys = generic

[logger_root]
level = INFO
handlers = console, applog

[logger_common]
level = DEBUG
handlers =
qualname = common

[logger_services]
level = DEBUG
handlers =
qualname = common.services

[logger_webapp]
level = DEBUG
handlers =
qualname = webapp

[logger_sqlalchemy]
level = WARN
handlers =
qualname = sqlalchemy.engine
# "level = INFO" logs SQL queries.
# "level = DEBUG" logs SQL queries and results.
# "level = WARN" logs neither.  (Recommended for production systems.)

[handler_console]
class = StreamHandler
args = (sys.stderr,)
level = DEBUG
formatter = generic

[handler_applog]
class = FileHandler
args = (r'%(here)s/log/app.log','a')
level = NOTSET
formatter = generic

[formatter_generic]
format = %(asctime)s %(levelname)-5.5s [%(name)s][%(threadName)s] %(message)s
```

Comment: I don't think you have set up your logging configuration correctly.  The local.ini file would typically be called from "pserve" when you start your server.  Manually setup logging in your test file.

Comment: If I want to run the webserver, yes, the command is `pserve src/local.ini --reload` or the like. But that runs the webserver... and doesn't provide me command-line access to the application, which is what `pshell src/local.ini` does. I want to see the logging the application is actually throwing *in pshell*, not in a manually set up test file that I can't then reasonably use in the application without a lot of additional work. In this case, the utility is something the application is actually using, and that I want to log with.

Comment: Don't you still have to configure your logging with something like this: 'logging.config.dictConfig(log_ini) '.   That's how I configure my logging using the dictionary method.  I forget the syntax for your local.ini file.  The logging config that you have in your local.ini is not being called since you are not using pserve.

Comment: http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/commandline.html  `pshell` absolutely does utilize the `.ini` file: you can load, for instance, orm objects and write to the database configured in that file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your root's logger logging level is set `INFO` which is higher level than `DEBUG` which is the level you log your messages with. Changing root's logger level to `DEBUG` should help.

Comment: Argh! That should have been obvious. Thanks!